# как создать динамический массив размером с получаемую строку С++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, память, ввод

В консоль вводится строка, размер которой заранее неизвестен. Как можно создать динамический массив размером с получаемую строку? Нельзя использовать string, только массивы char.

Comment: Читайте ее в `string`, дальше создаете массив размером с прочитанную строку. Устраивает?

Comment: Извините, не указал, что нельзя использовать string, только через массивы char.

Comment: Выделите массив из N байт, читайте посимвольно. Если не встретился `\n`, а массив заполнился - удваиваете его и читаете дальше...

Comment: Как то видел интересное решение с рекурсивным посимвольным чтением: там считанные символы сохранялись на стеке, а выделение памяти происходило на последнем шаге(когда нужный размер становился известен). при возврате из рекурсии считанные символы записывались в полученный буфер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Держите в честь праздника :)

```
char * read()
{
    int sz = 8, i = 0;
    char * buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*sz);
    for(int c = fgetc(stdin); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = fgetc(stdin))
    {
        buf[i++] = c;
        if (i == sz)
        {
            sz *= 2;
            buf = realloc(buf,sz);
        }
    }
    buf[i] = 0;
    return buf;
}
```

Полный код - https://ideone.com/kgX4Nb

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с одним выделением динамической памяти:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

char* read_line(FILE* input);

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> str;
    
    str.reset(read_line(stdin));
    
    std::cout << "read: [" << str.get() << "]" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
char* read_impl(FILE* input, size_t size, int ch);

char* read_line(FILE* input)
{
    return read_impl(input, 0, fgetc(input));
}

char* read_impl(FILE* input, size_t size, int ch)
{
    char* str;
    if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
    {
        str = new char [size + 1];
        str[size] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        str = read_impl(input, size + 1, fgetc(input));
        str[size] = char{ch};
    }
    return str;
}
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/xi2IBo)

**ВНИМАНИЕ**: может вызвать StackOverflow на длинных строках.

Comment: так а зачем вы юзаете рекурсию

Comment: Если человеку нельзя использовать string, то я даже не знаю, что ему скажут о unique_ptr

Comment: @Lofectr здесь стек используется в качестве временного буфера под считанные символы